# Does Enzyme test utility work with React.createClass?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, meteor, enzyme

Most of the component in my react+meteor app use the `React.createClass` api.
When I try to use render any of them in the test file using `render` or `mount`, it throws the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `Constructor`.
at invariant (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:23890:15)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:14982:134)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:15407:22)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:15298:21)
at Object.mountComponent (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:8128:35)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:15411:34)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:15298:21)
at Object.mountComponent (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:8128:35)
at mountComponentIntoNode (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:20348:32)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:9090:20)
```

Also, using `shallow` throws this error:

```
TypeError: Component is not a function
at packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:15346:16
at measureLifeCyclePerf (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:15115:12)
at ShallowComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:15345:14)
at ShallowComponentWrapper.mountComponent (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:15228:21)
at Object.mountComponent (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:8128:35)
at ReactShallowRenderer._render (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:21853:21)
at _batchedRender (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:21834:12)
at Object.batchedUpdates (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:17599:7)
at Object.batchedUpdates (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:7770:20)
at ReactShallowRenderer.render (packages/modules.js?hash=70ab85ea6ef331c0dda6aaba437ed823158e87bb:21827:16)
```

But if I render a component create using the `React.Component` api, it works perfectly fine. 
Now, my question is, does [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/) support the older `React.createClass` api?

Answer (score 1):

`Enzyme` is fine with `React.createClass`. See the test case below taken from one of `Enzyme` tests.

> https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/test/ShallowWrapper-spec.jsx#L13
>
> ```
> it('can pass in context', () => {
>   const SimpleComponent = React.createClass({
>     contextTypes: {
>       name: React.PropTypes.string,
>     },
>     render() {
>       return <div>{this.context.name}</div>;
>     },
>   });
>
>   const context = { name: 'foo' };
>   const wrapper = shallow(<SimpleComponent />, { context });
>   expect(wrapper.text()).to.equal('foo');
> });
> ```